# How do I insert the cursor after the last word (that is misspelled)?

Tags: ios, text-editor

Latest iOS, using Safari.  I am often writing a post on SE and the last word I left off on is a misspelling.  For instance

> ... so I definitely prefer QO to Homeline.
>
> *

*The misspelled word is jargon or a trade name.*

Now, I want to continue writing.  So I place the cursor at the asterisk above: the beginning of the next paragraph (I had hit new line twice after the misspelled word). Instead, it lights up the last word in red.  I cannot type because the word and new lines will be destroyed and I will be adding to the previous paragraph.

What is the proper way to put the cursor at the end of the word or the start of the next paragraph?

Comment: The answer may differ depending on the app/context. Can you clarify in what app you're doing this?

Comment: @Monomeeth Good point, it's Safari/latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press on empty space after any text until a sort of magnifying glass appears over your finger.

Move your finger to the cursor and keep going.  The cursor will follow you in the center of the magnifier.  When you get it where you want, let go.